# Ansible doesn't change privilage from USAGE to GRANT ALL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ansible

I used following ansible task to GRANT ALL privilege to all databases.

```
- name: create new user {{ db_user }} with all privilege
  mysql_user: name="{{ db_user }}"
              password="{{ db_password }}"
              append_privs=yes
              priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT state=present
```

but when I run `show grants for 'dbuser'@'XX.XX.XX.XX';` on mysql`(mariadb)` it shows me following.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'XX.XX.XX.XX' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A7AD1ECBCD787B8CABE6A58AEA652A8B3CF5035BA82'
```

How to change this USAGE to GRANT ALL using ansible?

Comment: Are the spaces next to the braces important?  That is, are you working with `' db_user '` or `'db_user'`?

Comment: I added space because of clearness anyway, Jinja2 template engine works fine with or without spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `mysql_user` creates users with `localhost` host portion.
So your task created `dbuser@localhost` with `GRANT ALL`.
If you need another host, set `host=XX.XX.XX.XX` parameter for the module.
Also there is `host_all=yes` available since 2.1 when modifying permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

````
mysql_user:
    name: root
    host: "{{item}}"
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    host_all: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - 127.0.0.1
    - ::1
    - localhost
```
````